# how to passing post variable values into array?

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array, country

i have a code which is not working properly i want to when `user's select country from drop down select list`? After form is submitted value should be store into `courier array`?

**For Example**

if user selected Usa then Usa should be match with the `abc courier array values` if the value are matched to each others then `$_SESSION['country1']=$abc;`will be create?

**Senorio**

i have two different courier companies and i want to passing countries list according to the courier companies to the another page?

**Index Page**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_REQUEST['test']))
{
$newcountry=$_POST['country'];  

//Let's Assume Courier Companies Is Abc
$abc=array($newcountry=>'Usa',$newcountry=>'Uk');

//Let's Assume Another Courier Companies Is Xyz
$xyz=array($newcountry=>'Singapore',$newcountry=>'Germany');

$_SESSION['country1']=$abc;
$_SESSION['country2']=$xyz;

if(isset($_SESSION['country1']) && isset($_SESSION['country2'])){
header('Location:test.php'); 
}}
?>

<form method="post">
<select name="country" id="country">
<option value="Usa">Usa</option>
<option value="Uk">Uk</option>
<option value="Germany">Germany</option>
<option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
<input type="submit" name="test" value="Submit" />

</select>
</form>
```

**Test.php**

```
session_start();
echo $country2=implode($_SESSION['country1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newcountry=$_POST['country'];  

//Let's Assume Courier Companies Is Abc
$abc=array($newcountry=>'Usa',$newcountry=>'Uk');

//Let's Assume Another Courier Companies Is Xyz
$xyz=array($newcountry=>'Singapore',$newcountry=>'Germany');
```

Your array assignment of $abc and $xyz results in a single element. If "Usa" is selected $abc = array("Usa" => "Uk") and $xyz = array("Usa" => "Germany") as the value for the $newcountry is the same and the latter value resets the formal value.

Comment: when i `echo $country2=implode($_SESSION['country1']);` on the `test.page` then it is showing usauk together but i want then user's or customer's select country then country value should be check into array then it will be echo single country which is select by the user or customer?